# is it possible for items in a table to be a list in Q

Tags: kdb

I wonder if its possible to make items of a table to be a list? I have tried to do something like

```
table:([] name:`a`b`c; food:`apple`peach;`meat`vegg;`cat`dog)
```

but it didnt work.
is there anyway I can do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely have lists as items in a table. In fact, you can even have nested tables, since tables behave like lists of dictionaries.

```
q)table:([] name:`a`b`c; food:(`apple`peach;`meat`vegg;`cat`dog))
q)table
name food
----------------
a    apple peach
b    meat  vegg
c    cat   dog
q)nested:([] t:(table;table))
q)nested
t
-------------------------------------------------------
+`name`food!(`a`b`c;(`apple`peach;`meat`vegg;`cat`dog))
+`name`food!(`a`b`c;(`apple`peach;`meat`vegg;`cat`dog))
```

Public learning resources for q and KDB is probably a little weak if you are used to something like Java or Python, but the [KX wiki](http://code.kx.com) is a pretty good place to start.